# Optimizing Postgresql Query for a Subquery

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by, query-optimization

I'm pretty new to postgres and this is probably a novice question. How can I improve this query?

Three tables, `campaigns` 1-->M `threads` 1-->M `messages`. I have the campaign ID and I want all the threads with their total individual `opens`, `clicks` and `replies` counts of all the related messages where `opens` and `clicks` are in a JSONB field named `extra` under `messages` and replies are the `messages` that have column `"direction"='received'`.

```
select "threads".*, 
count("messages"."extra"->'opens') as opens, 
count("messages"."extra"->'clicks') as clicks, 
(
    select count("messages"."id")
    from "messages" 
    where "messages"."thread_id" = "threads"."id" 
    and "messages"."direction"='received'
) as replies
from "threads" 
inner join "messages" 
on "messages"."thread_id" = "threads"."id" 
where "threads"."campaign_id" 
in ('campaign_uuid') 
group by "threads"."id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that you can just do a conditional count:

```
select 
    t.id, 
    sum(jsonb_array_length(m.extra->'opens')) as opens, 
    sum(jsonb_array_length(m.extra->'clicks')) as clicks, 
    count(*) filter(where m.direction='received') as replies
from threads t
inner join messages m on m.thread_id = t.id 
where t.campaign_id = 'campaign_uuid'
group by t.id
```

Notes:

- if opens and clicks are jsonb arrays, you can use `jsonb_array_length()` to compute their lengths
- you need to enumerate in the `group by` clause all non-aggregated columns from the `select` clause - so `select *` and `grup by` do not go along well together; I modified the query to only select `threads.id`; if you want more columns from `threads` then you should add them in both the `select` and `group by` clauses.
- do not use double quotes around identifiers unless they are really needed (which does not seem to be the case in your query)
- table aliases make the query easier to read and write

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I just figured out my query is wrong. `clicks` and `opens` are array. count(m.extra->'opens') counts as one even if there are multiple items in the array. How do I get total counts? Think I needed SUM.

Comment: @Rocky . . . This answers the question that you originally asked.  If you have a different question, you should ask as a *new* question.  I would also suggest that you include sample data and desired results as well.

Comment: @Rocky: you can use `jsonb_array_length()` to compute the number of items in an array.

Comment: I have all the answers now. Thank you for your help (y)